# How do I secure API access in Laravel 4 with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

I am a newbie to Laravel4 and I have following setup:
(1) Back End in Laravel and 
(2) Front End in AngularJS

I would like to know how I can restrict access to API. I implemented a Auth Token based system which is set by the front end when making  API requests.

However, anyone can use check Network call, copy the Access/Auth Token and use it to make API requests. How do I secure my API to prevent such an attack by someone who can copy the Auth Token?

Comment: There should be no problem letting the user fire off requests using his own token. The danger is if user X uses the token of user A, but that's what HTTPS is for :)

Comment: I agree with @JimLm; ensure communication with API is through HTTPS and you'll have no problems. In Laravel's `routes.php` file you can also put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://yourwebsite.com');` And I think you meant to say Laravel 4 in your question, not Laravel 2.

Comment: @cornflakes24 I believe sireesha is wondering how to prevent the logged in user from taking their token and simply plugging it into a non-web client and making calls from there

Comment: Hmm, the question states "I would like to know how I can restrict access to API"; so I'm just giving my ideas. This is something I'm looking into right now as well.

Comment: @LocNguyen is right. How can one prevent using the token from a non-web client?

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTPS, the communication would be encrypted and no ne should be able to sniff the Token on your network.

Comment: how about when someone uses firebug to see the header information and thus copy the token to use it in non-web client?

Comment: Firebug allows you acces only to your own data. Thus, one user won't be able to use firebug to see another user traffic data. And even if they se a sniffer, if the data is transmitted thru HTTPS, it won't be readable.